# How to set Django Template to always include an Achor tag?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, anchor

I'd like to have a View served up from Django to always include an anchor tag.

Trying to get the link below?

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/credit#start
```

Many thanks.

Comment: are you open to using jQuery to achieve this ? If not, you can write a middleware which detects the URL, and appends an anchor tag.

Comment: @karthikr: Glad you again on django questions, and yes, I think this is totally client side, its best to keep it client side as well.

Comment: @karthikr I can use JQuery here just kinda curious about how to pull it off the other way.  ;)  Thanks for the help.

Comment: The middleware is added overhead over every request. I would do it the jQuery way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, what you want is not a django or python or a server-side problem, but rather client-side. In my experience, try to hand over as much of the weight of processing as you can towards client side js, that way you have less pressure on your server.

Now, you can do this with a nice and neat jquery library plugin [here](http://www.jqueryscript.net/layout/jQuery-Auto-Anchored-Heading-Elements-Plugin-Anchorify-js.html).

Comment: I was thinking something very simple. On page load, trigger a `$('#start').click()`

Comment: @karthikr: Yea, totally get that, but this little extension will give him aut-generated anchors, so he won't be confused if he wants to add more anchors.